# Tagdata Fetch Params Not Accepting JSON String

Tags: templates, tags, parameters, json

EE 5.2.4

I'm developing a feature for custom analytics. Certain activities are saved as channel entries in order to be presented in a dashboard later.

I have the first part of the feature working. The way I've gone about it is to save the activity as a string of JSON in a channel entry field. My intention was to parse this out later, as I'm not sure what sort of technology I'll be using on the dashboard and JSON seemed like a universal/consistent format to store the data.

My issue is when I try to pass the JSON string as a tag parameter into a php class method, it doesn't like the JSON and returns nothing.

Example.

Template:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='analytics' dynamic='no' status='not closed'}
    {exp:class:my_method json='{json}'}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Class:

```
  function my_method() {

    $json = ee()->TMPL->fetch_param('json');
    print_r($json);
  }
```

When the `{json}` is the saved JSON string from the channel (I know that's working because it shows just fine in the template), the `$json` variable will return nothing, but if I replace `{json}` in `json='{json}'` with a normal string or even another entry field like `{title}` it will work just fine and I'll get a correct print.

Any ideas what's happening to this JSON string?

I *could* use php to work with this data in the template, for example

```
<? php 
   $json = '{json}';
   print_r(json_decode($json, true));
?>
```

but I'd **really** rather use the EE template features if possible because I just like them so much.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Tags in params aren't going to be parsed unless you add this parameter:

```
parse="inward"
```

The parse order stuff is... hard to grok. Try adding that to your channel entry tag.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/templates/language.html#changing-parsing-order

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm not sure I understand, though. I added `parse='inward'` to my channel entry tag and the result changed from nothing to `'}`. In the documentation you linked it uses an rss_parser tag? `{exp:rss_parser url="https://ellislab.com/blog/rss-feed" limit="5" parse="inward"}`

Comment: Hrmm. The issue there might be that your JSON string actually has single quotes in it, resulting in a parameter that ends up looking like this: `json='{'key': 'value'}'` which would confuse the parser. Try putting a plain string like `test` into your JSON field and see if it gets passed correctly.

Comment: And the doc example is just that; and example. Ignore the `rss_parse` tag, it could be any EE method tag.